# How risky is it to proxy an oauth SSO flow?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, cross-domain, amazon-cognito, pkce

So, I have multiple projects, api, etc... And i'd like to have a central sign-in system. So I turn to SSO and the openId PKCE flow.

Let's say I want to use some cloud solution to save time and money - hypothetically, let's say AWS cognito, for its good integration with aws product.

Now let's say my cloud solution is still pretty much half backed in many regards compared to the competition and to my needs, for example we could imagine the hosted ui of the oauth sso login page cannot be properly customized or even translated, which is a no-go.

Now, we can imagine that we understand oauth PKCE code grant flow, and that we build a small server, or a couple of lambdas, to proxy the oauth implementation so that we can build an alternative front. The server would :

1. make the inital authorize request with the code_challenge provided by the client application, get a state - or in the case of cognito a csrf token - and return that to our "custom login font".
2. The "custom login front" could call our server with the csrf, the login and the password, and our server in turn would call the login endpoint of the oauth cloud solution, and check if the response is a redirect to our callback with the code provided - grab that code and return it to the login front for it to finally do the redirect after a nice loader has finished moving.

Would it be bad to do such thing, especially knowing that the login POST request to our oauth cloud solution might have to set a dishonest "HOST" header for the request to pass if we cannot host the login front and server on the same domain as our oauth cloud solution ?

And, finally, am I making sense at all ?

Comment: If you try to intercept the username/password, you will quickly be banned. I am not aware of any Identity Providers that allow that in their terms of service. A security researcher would publish your site as being dangerous. Most Identity Providers have more complicated methods of detecting what you are trying to do. The best that you will accomplish is locking someone's account and that won't go over very well. I use MFA on all of my accounts - how are you going to get around that technique?

Comment: I won't intercept external oauth providers. Social login will go their own flow. I am trying to build a custom front over my own identity pool on add cognito - my own users etc... so no mfa or anything. I could build an oauth provider that support pkce flow, and get proper token from cognito by api logon, but that's part what I am paying for when using cognito isn't it ?

Comment: Edit your question. You state `The "custom login front" could call our server with the csrf, the login and the password, and our server in turn would call the login endpoint of the oauth cloud solution ...` That is capturing the username / password.